# How to get local time when Azure Data Factory Linked Service parses Timezone offset to UTC

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a data factory pipeline that receives JSON files from an Azure Blob storage.

These files have the following structure:

```
{
"Time": {
    "UTC": {
        "Sent": "2020-09-01T11:45:00.0Z"
    }
},
    "LocalTime": {
        "Original": {
            "Sent": "2020-09-01T13:45:00+02:00"
        }
    }
```

}

When the lookup data activity gets the file from the blob it parses the localtime to UTC. I would like to ignore the offset and just grab the datetime as is.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: We decided to solve this by stripping the offset with regex while moving the folder to the blob using a logic app.

Comment: Hi @Sixsmith, We are glad to hear that you use another way to solve the issue.. It should be posted as the answer and I just help you do that. You can think about accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Sixsmith, hope you are doing well, did you figure it out with logic app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your comment:

- We decided to solve this by stripping the offset with regex while
  moving the folder to the blob using a logic app.

We are glad to hear that you found a solution to solve it. I help you post it as answer, others can ref this way. This also can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the ask , as definitely I had never thought it would behave the way its did . For clarity of others when we try
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.LocalTime.Original.Sent will give the output as "2020-09-01T11:45Z" and not "2020-09-01T13:45:00+02:00".

This is what I tried while creating the Dataset , create it as if the file is delimited and not JSON ( this is what i think you are doing ) and the intend is to read the content of the whole file as string . Please make the adjustment to the Column& row limiter as shown below [image]

Now you can use the expression ( i hate to hard code , but then we can suyre make it dynamic )

```
@substring(string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow),187,16)


Output
{
    "name": "Datepart",
    "value": "2020-09-01T13:45"
}
```

HTH